# calling getScript inside an ajax load callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Can somebody please explain this to me.
The goal here is to load via an ajax call an external html, and then load and execute an external script associated with that html code.

Code A:

```
$('#content').load(toLoad,function(){
        $.getScript("toLoadScript.js");
});
```

Code B:

```
$('#content').load(toLoad,showNewContent());
function showNewContent() {
    $.getScript("toLoadScript.js");
}
```

Code C:

```
$('#content').load(toLoad,showNewContent);
function showNewContent() {
    $.getScript("toLoadScript.js");
}
```

Why is it that only Code C succesfully loads and executes the script while the other 2 doesn't.

question related to: [Jquery: Run script after ajax load()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773600/jquery-run-script-after-ajax-load)

Comment: b is definitely not supposed to work; a should though

Comment: no reason `A` shouldn't work. `B` needs to use function reference without `()`

Comment: my bad.. i retested my code and sure enough A does work though I could have swore it didn't before, and ye I just realized why B wont work as well. silly me..

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: **why Code B doesn't work**

In Code B you are invoking `.load` as follows:

```
$('#content').load(toLoad,showNewContent());
```

Which essentially breaks down into:

```
var newContent = showNewContent();
$('#content').load(toLoad,newContent);
```

So you are invoking `showNewContent` and passing the result of that into `.load`.

This is not what you want to do. Instead you should pass the function itself (and not its result) to `load`:

```
$('#content').load(toLoad,showNewContent);
```