# jQuery execute script after everything ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax in my webpage and I have some javascript in the ajax page which will be executed when the ajax page is load. But the problem is, how can I have jquery to only execute the script after that ajax page is completely loaded?

I have tried with:

```
$( '#ajaxdiv' ).load(function() {

}
```

But it didn't run the code at all. If I put it `.ready()`, then it does run the code, but not after everything is loaded.

Is it possible to have a piece of code that will only executed after everything is completely ready?

Comment: ajax page? Not sure I understand what that is.

Comment: The URL parameter is obligatory in jQuery's `.load()`. A function goes last. But I'm not quite sure I 100% understand the question.

Comment: can you show more of your code? I assume you run mutliple ajax requests? $(document).ready() executes when the document is fully loaded not when all ajax requests are complete, you might need to use the callbacks of the ajax functions to run the remainder of your code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773600/jquery-run-script-after-ajax-load

Comment: If possible, can post `html`, `js` ?

Comment: Perhaps you can call the script you want excecuted in the succes statement of the ajax call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look in to the deferred promise object. This is a decent article explaining what it is / how to use it.

**Deferred Object**
http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

http://css-tricks.com/multiple-simultaneous-ajax-requests-one-callback-jquery/
(Sample Code from the article below. )

```
$.when(
  // Get the HTML
  $.get("/feature/", function(html) {
    globalStore.html = html;
  }),

  // Get the CSS
  $.get("/assets/feature.css", function(css) {
    globalStore.css = css;
  }),

  // Get the JS
  $.getScript("/assets/feature.js")

).then(function() {

  // All is ready now, so...

  // Add CSS to page
  $("<style />").html(globalStore.css).appendTo("head");

  // Add HTML to page
  $("body").append(globalStore.html);

});
```