# Is there document.ready equivalent for page with AJAX loaded sections?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a main page containing a number of sections. Each of these sections defines a (document).ready event, calling a function. The function is unique, and defined within the section itself.
E.g.

Main.htm

section1 :Defines funcABC(). (document).ready calls funcABC();

section2 :Defines funcDEF(). (document).ready calls funcDEF();

section3 :Defines funcXYZ(). (document).ready calls funcXYZ();

etc..

So the page loads, and each section calls the function it needs, and everything works.

The page has now been changed to load the sections via AJAX (jquery.load()). The layout shown above no longer works as (document).ready only fires when Main.htm loads, but not the sections have loaded.

Main.htm can't call the functions in the sections as it doesn't know which each section needs, and doesn't have the definitions (which are dynamically generated in each section).

I know the design is strange, it's something I've inherited and have to work with..

I basically need each section to its own function after it loads, as it was doing. How can I make this work?

Comment: You should be able to specify the function calls in a callback function to jquery.load(). Put your definitions for each section's function as callbacks per section.

Comment: i think this post might be what you are looking for [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773600/jquery-run-script-after-ajax-load][1]
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773600/jquery-run-script-after-ajax-load

Comment: the `ajax` method of jquery allows for several handlers (`done`, `fail`, `always`) that you can exploit for your purpose. insert the loaded section as the first instruction in the success handler, call the section-specific function afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(document).ready` is a handler for the event when you load the DOM, however, you trigger some AJAX events and you want to execute a function when the event finished successfully. The functions executed when the server responded are called callback functions. Let's suppose you have a function, like this:

```
function() myFunction {
    //...
}
```

you want `myFunction` to be executed as a callback function. Let's suppose you use a `jquery.load`, like this:

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html", function() {
   myFunction();
});
```

This is an event handler, which sends a request to `"ajax/test.html"` and when response has arrived, executes an unnamed function passed as parameter. This unnamed function calls `myFunction`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have multiple AJAX calls and would like to do something after they've all finished. This has nothing to do with the jQuery(document).ready() which is related to the loading of the DOM. It's your application's logic.

A bare-bones solution (a bit ad-hoc) would be as follows:

1. If you're using [`jQuery.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) calls, they all have the `done`/`fail`/`always` callbacks you can use to notify some other function that they're done (if you're not using `jQuery.ajax`, then find the relevant hook/callback and adjust the code example below accordingly).
2. Then you could do something after 3 ajax calls have finished:

.

```
function ABC(){
  $.ajax({url:'...'}).always(waitForThemToFinish);
}
function DEF(){
  $.ajax({url:'...'}).always(waitForThemToFinish);
}
function GHI(){
  $.ajax({url:'...'}).always(waitForThemToFinish);
}

var finished = 0;
function waitForThemToFinish(){
  if (finished < 3) { // To ensure that the operation below is called only once
    finished++;
    if (finished >= 3) {
      // do something after some 3 ajax calls have finished
    }    
  }
}
```