# How to create new Bootstrap select picker controls on HTML loaded by AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The  "Bootstrap-Select" script is working well for content when I refresh page. When I change option in select I get new content for `#ajax_filter` but the script Bootstrap-Select is not working. How can I reload this script after an AJAX response?

```
<!-- in <head> -->
<script id="bselect1" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<div id="#ajax_filter">
  <select name='components[]' class="selectpicker form-control components" id='cheese' data-live-search="true" data-count-selected-text='<span class="label label-danger">{0}</span> Ser' title='<span class="label label-danger">0</span> Ser' multiple data-selected-text-format="count > 0">
    <option value="aaaa">AAA</option>
    <option value="bbbb">BBBB</option>
  </select>
</div>

<script>
  $(function(){ 
    $('.components').on('change',function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'menu/ajax_filter',
        data: { 'components': components, 'size': size }, 
        type: "post",
        success: function(data) {
          $("#ajax_filter").hide().html(data).fadeIn('fast');
          $('#bselect1').remove();
          $.getScript("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js", function() {
            $('script:last').attr('id', 'bselect1');
          });
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This link will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773600/jquery-run-script-after-ajax-load

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach isn't quite right. You don't want to create a new `<script>` element that references the library to create new instances of the control - that will actually cause more problems that it solves.

Instead you need to initialise the library on the new elements directly by calling the `selectpicker()` function on them after the AJAX call completes and the DOM is updated, like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'menu/ajax_filter',
  data: { 'components': components, 'size': size }, 
  type: "post",
  success: function(data){
    $("#ajax_filter").hide().html(data).fadeIn('fast').find('.your-select-elements').selectpicker();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Your soulution is working but i have 2 new problems:
1) selectpicker forgets selected options
2) after ajax response $('.components').on('change',function()  not working again.

Comment: Problem nr 2 solved -  $(document).on('change', '.components', function()

Answer (score 1):

You may want to refresh your selectpicker.

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```